# Multiple values on one cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

The code I wrote should store multiple user values on one cookie, but for some reason it's not working. Can anyone care to explain my mistake?

```js
var delimiter = "#";

function createCookie(name, value, days, path, domain, secure) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = date.toGMTString();
  } else var expires = "";
  cookieString = name + "=" + escape(value);
  if (expires)
    cookieString += "; expires=" + expires;
  if (path)
    cookieString += "; path=" + escape(path);
  if (domain)
    cookieString += "; domain=" + escape(domain);
  if (secure)
    cookieString += "; secure";
  document.cookie = cookieString;
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var nameEquals = name + "=";
  var whole_cookie = document.cookie.split(nameEquals)[1].split(";")[0];
  var crumbs = whole_cookie.split(delimiter);
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name, "", -1);
}

function myCookie() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  var userdata = name + delimiter + age;
  createCookie("user", userdata);
  var myUser = getCookie('user');
  var myUserArray = myUser.split(delimiter);
  var cookieName = myUserArray[0];
  var cookieAge = myUserArray[1];
  alert('The cookie created has the following user information stored on it: \nName: ' + cookieName '\nAge: ' + cookieAge);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Please enter your name
<input type=text id='name' />
<br>
<br>Please enter your age
<input type=text id='name' />
<input type=button value='Go!' onClick='myCookie()' />
```

Comment: Side note: JavaScript convention is `camelCase`, not `snake_case`.

Comment: Why not use a dedicated library for this? Like [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), it's less prone to errors and your code will be more readable.

Comment: @ShanShan under normal circumstances, believe me, but for this particular project I have to do it the old fashioned way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code:

1. In `getCookie`, you forgot to return the value of your cookie !

   ```
   function getCookie(name) {
       var nameEquals = name + "=";
       var whole_cookie=document.cookie.split(nameEquals)[1].split(";")[0];         
       return whole_cookie;
   }
   ```
2. You have two inputs with id `name`, I think you want to rename one of them to `age`.
3. Make sure your document is fully loaded before you try to execute your Javascript! Either do that by wrapping your code around `document.body.onload = function(){ [your code here] }`, or by moving your `<script>` tag at the end of your document.
4. You are missing a `+` between `cookieName` and `'\nAge'` in your `alert`.

---

```js
var delimiter = "#";

function createCookie(name, value, days, path, domain, secure) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = date.toGMTString();
  } else var expires = "";
  cookieString = name + "=" + escape(value);
  if (expires)
    cookieString += "; expires=" + expires;
  if (path)
    cookieString += "; path=" + escape(path);
  if (domain)
    cookieString += "; domain=" + escape(domain);
  if (secure)
    cookieString += "; secure";
  document.cookie = cookieString;
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var nameEquals = name + "=";
  var whole_cookie = document.cookie.split(nameEquals)[1].split(";")[0];
  return whole_cookie;
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name, "", -1);
}

function myCookie() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  var userdata = name + delimiter + age;
  createCookie("user", userdata);
  var myUser = getCookie('user');
  var myUserArray = myUser.split(delimiter);
  var cookieName = myUserArray[0];
  var cookieAge = myUserArray[1];
  alert('The cookie created has the following user information stored on it: \nName: ' + cookieName + '\nAge: ' + cookieAge);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Please enter your name
<input type=text id='age' />
<br>
<br>Please enter your age
<input type=text id='name' />
<input type=button value='Go!' onClick='myCookie()' />
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I stepped away from my computer but I'll try this as soon as I get back!